# Clicking link in form updates textarea after passing it to php file to process

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

My Google-Fu was weak today.

I'd appreciate any advice or links to tutorials to add the following to a form.

Let's say I have a data entry form for putting news stories into a database. I also have a db of names and bios and their corresponding urls. I already have a php script that searches the news database for mentions of people that aren't linked to their bios.

I'd like to automate the process a bit. After I type a story in the form, but before I submit it, I'd like to click a link, say "Link bios", that passes the textarea to a php script that adds the links and puts the updated story back into the textarea, so I can then submit the form.

I'm a cut'n'paste and study tutorials kinda coder. So I know I need Ajax or jQuery but I can't code it with my eyes closed. If you can point me to a way that sends a textarea to a php file and then sends it back, I'd appreciate any pointers. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So let's say that you have a link that says "Link Bios", let's give it an ID of "link-bios" for brevity.

```
<a href="#" id="link-bios"> Link Bios </a>
```

Now, we need the textarea. Let's give this an id of "textarea" For brevity.

```
<textarea id="textarea" name="textarea"></textarea>
```

Now, we need to build the click function on link-bios so it will grab the content of the textarea and submit it to a PHP script for processing. here's how that'll look:

```
$('#link-bios').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); //prevent the default click action on the anchor elemeent

    //create a cachable reference to our textarea.
    var textarea = $('#textarea');

    /**
     * Construct the ajax request to send data to the server.
     * replace URL with your path to your script.
     * store the ajax reference so we can call .done() to retrieve data from server after it performs it's logic
     */
    var db_request = $.ajax({
        url: '/path/to/my/script.php', //adjust this accordingly
        type: 'POST', //post method for the server
        data: {
            textarea: textarea.val() //create a key value pair so we can access this value with $_POST['textarea'] on the server
        },
        dataType: 'json' //we expect JSON to come back from the server
    });

    //when the PHP script is done, the server response will be available here.
    db_request.done(function(response){
        /**
         * Because we expect JSON, we can access the properties directly here.
         * We also replace the textareas' value with the response value.
         */
         textarea.val(response.text);
    });
});
```

Now, on the server side, we just need to make sure we return proper JSON after we've performed all of our logic.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['textarea'])){
    //logic here to do your database work.

    $text = //we assume that the text you want to send BACK is stored here.

    echo json_encode(array(
        'text' => $text
    ));
}
```

Now the above script will send back the json encoded array containing the text that we parse in our `.done()` function from above. It will be placed into the textarea as well.

I hope this was helpful.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give this a look after lunch!

Comment: Worked like a charm. One quick edit though: `if(isset($POST['textarea']))` should be `if(isset($_POST['textarea']))`

Answer (score 1):

So you would send an AJAX POST to your PHP route with your textarea data, then in your PHP script run whatever processes on your DB, and return the updated textarea data for your AJAX call to consume. A bit of code to get your started..

```
var textareaContent = $("#textareaID").val();

$.ajax(function() {
    method: "POST",
    url: "/yourRoute",
    data: {
        content: textareaContent
    }
}).success(function(returnedData) {
    // using return in your PHP script returns that data to this variable returnedData
    $("#textareaID").val(returnedData);

}).error(function() {
    // Do something here on error
});
```

Comment: Thanks as well to you Graham. Will try some code shortly.